# Dynamic classnames in Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I am using Next.js and React.js. I want to change a tailwind tag dynamically regarding where the component is used.

```
export default function GradientContent({
  gradientPercentage = 30,
  
  //...

<div className={twMerge("bg-gradient-to-b from-black",
                   "from-" + gradientPercentage + "%",
          )}
>
```

But it doesn't work when I call the component by setting the value of the variable `gradientPercentage` to an integer value.